# how to get column name from mongodb in java

Tags: java, mongodb

How can I get Column Name i.e Name,LocalName,Dept_ID?

```
 public  Document createSeedData(){           
    d=new Document();     
    d.append("Name", CatName.getText());
    d.append("LocalName", LocalName.getText());
    d.append("Dept_ID", 1);
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call the method entrySet() on the Document item returned.

```
Document d  = createSeedData();

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : d.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Explaining of course that a BSON Document class inherits the Map interface.

Comment: In my case I have to convert (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : seedData.entrySet()) to for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : seedData.entrySet()).Why so?

Comment: And what will be answer If i do not insert data in this file but data is there in collection and only want to fetch column name.

Comment: @DrashtiPandya it depends on what you put in as to what the map will look like when retrieving it....

"And what will be answer If i do not insert data in this file but data is there in collection and only want to fetch column name"

Could you give an example please

Comment: Yes.When you click on generate report button all data should be fetch and should insert in PDF.That time we haven't do perform Insert function.

Comment: @DrashtiPandya Sorry what I meant by example is do you have a code example for the insert and then for the retrieval of the data and what you are trying to use it for.

Comment: I have done it through sql but don't know how to do in MongoDB.If you wish to see I can send you test case on your mail ID.